# What is the difference between “comprehension”, “perception” and "sensation"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, vocabulary

I searched these words but there is no information comparing these three words at once. I probably should post the question in a psychology forum.

Comment: Hi Aryasinic! Dictionaries don't compare words: *you* have to do that. Why don't you look up their meanings and then compare them?

Comment: Where did the question come from?

Comment: Previously asked: [What is the difference between “comprehend” and “perceive”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156537/what-is-the-difference-between-comprehend-and-perceive) There is quite a lot of other material easily found too.

Comment: I'm looking for suitable equivalents for these terms in my language. The current equivalents are confusing. The equivalent for "comprehension" and "perception" is the same. I will ask it in a psychology forum. Thanks guys!